# Training 'en_core_web_sm' model of Spacy v2.0.11 fails

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train the `en_core_web_sm` model to add a new entity `EMAIL` using the below code:

```
LABEL = "EMAIL"
    TRAIN_DATA = [
        (
            "My email address is XXXX@gmail.com",
            {"entities": [(20, 37, LABEL)]},
        ),
        ("you can email me @ XXXXX@ai.xXx.com?", {"entities": [(19, 36, LABEL)]}),
        (
            "contact me @ XXXX@ai.xXX.com",
            {"entities": [(13, 31, LABEL)]},
        ),
    ("you can contact me at xxXX@xxXXX.com", {"entities": [(22, 56, LABEL)]})
    ]

def main(model="en_core_web_sm", new_model_name="en_core_web_sm", output_dir="D:/Train_ai", n_iter=8):
    random.seed(0)
    if model is not None:
        nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  
        print("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank("en") 
        print("Created blank 'en' model")
    if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
        nlp.add_pipe(ner)
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

    ner.add_label(LABEL)  
    ner.add_label("VEGETABLE")
    if model is None:
        optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    else:
        optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
```

The error I get is:

> AttributeError: 'English' object has no attribute 'resume_training'" on line `optimizer = nlp.resume_training()`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3524), the `resume_training` attribute was only added in spaCy v2.1.x. It looks like you're running an older version, v2.0.11. So you'd either have to upgrade your spaCy installation, or rewrite your code to not use `resume_training`. To see the code examples for a given version, you can navigate to the respective tag on GitHub. For instance, [see here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/v2.0.18/examples) for the code examples of the latest v2.0.x.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @Ines, Spacy 2.0.x doesn't support `resume_training`. But you can still resume training of your checkpoint by simply replacing this line:

```
optimizer =  nlp.resume_training()
```

with this line:

```
optimizer = nlp.entity.create_optimizer()
```

And then while `nlp.update()` at the last where training actually starts, pass this to `sgd` param like this:

```
nlp.update(
                texts,  # batch of texts
                annotations,  # batch of annotations
                sgd=optimizer,
                drop=0,   # dropout - make it harder to memorise data
                losses=losses, 
            )
```

Resuming the training can be helpful for a variety of tasks like fine-tuning / adding new entity / restarting training in case of interruptions.